# What is the difference between grabbed and restrained?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions

This is not a question about the mechanical effects. I'm just trying to figure out why 4e defines two effects that appear to be the same. If something is grabbed, isn't it in effect also restrained? If something is restrained wouldn't it also be grabbed by something? As a DM, I'm trying to figure out when/where I would use one effect over another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use *restrained* over *grabbed* in circumstances where the victim isn't just prevented from moving away, but also otherwise inconvenienced. (That's where the -2 and "grants combat advantage" come in.) Consider "held firmly by the arm" and "wrapped up in animated vines."

Comment: In other words, restrained is a more intense form of grabbed.

Answer (score 6):

If I've got your wrist in one of my hands, you're grabbed. If I've got a rope around your belly, again, grabbed.

If I've got both your wrists behind your back, you're restrained. If my rope is pinning your arms, you're probably restrained.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that you could grab something a lot larger than you, but not restrain it?

Comment: It's a lot harder to restrain something that's bigger and/or stronger than you. Not imposible, but unlikely. Vera, one of the Security Guards when I was in high school, more than once simply picked up peeved football players who outmassed her by double, and had 2' of height on her. Kept them from getting suspended.

Comment: That's still in the same size category though. I'm thinking S vs M or M vs L.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbed - in simple terms means to "hold" or "stop" something. Restrained is more of "restriction" type wherein the object is not able to execute a particular action